# How can I show the contents of a R data file on R?

Tags: r, dataset

I was able to load the document using

load("/Users/p/Downloads/Returns.Rdata")
but i don't know how to see thee contents inside, how can I see what's in the file?

Comment: Try with:
load("/Users/p/Downloads/Returns.Rdata")
head(Returns, n = 5)

The parameter n determines the number of rows to be displayed in the terminal